# Does torch.manual_seed include the operation of torch.cuda.manual_seed_all?

Tags: python, random, pytorch, random-seed

Does `torch.manual_seed` include the operation of `torch.cuda.manual_seed_all`?

If yes, we can just use `torch.manual_seed` to set the seed. Otherwise we should call both functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, [`torch.manual_seed()`](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/difference-between-torch-manual-seed-and-torch-cuda-manual-seed/13848) does include CUDA:

> You can use `torch.manual_seed()` to seed the RNG for all devices (both CPU and CUDA):

- https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/randomness.html

Answer (score 1):

See [Pytorch lightning's `seed_everything`](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/pytorch_lightning/utilities/seed.html):

```
random.seed(seed)
np.random.seed(seed)
torch.manual_seed(seed)
torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed)
```

Makes me believe these are all and only the required seeds.

Comment: There may be [other sources of randomness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67511658/training-pytorch-models-on-different-machines-leads-to-different-results/67511954#67511954) in PyTorch models, depending on the specific modules/functions used.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `torch.manual_seed` calls `torch.cuda.manual_seed_all` internally.

Additional evidence other than [@iacob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9067615/iacob)'s answer can be found in the [PyTorch source code](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/random.html#manual_seed)

```py
def manual_seed(seed) -> torch._C.Generator:
    ...

    if not torch.cuda._is_in_bad_fork():
        torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed)

    ...
```